# Expand and collapse based on the key - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created an array as follows :

```
const title = ['hello', 'secondTitle', 'thirdTitle']
```

And I have a component where I need to pass title as property,
I also have a service that returns an object with members : HelloContent, secondtitleContent, thirdTitleContent

```
<CustomComponent listTitle = {title} toggleExpanded= {toggleExpanded} pass corresponding data?>
```

I also have a state variable :

```
constructor(props) {
    state: {
      expanded: false
     }
}

toggleExpanded = () => {
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})
}
```

So what I want to do is :
Iterate through the array,
Pass the title to the CustomComponent and I'm also passing toggleExpanded ( which expands and collapses the view).
But how do I pass for every item in the array to expand its current view, because this way, if I expand one, all components expand.

Do I change expanded to be an array [] ?
Any suggestions ?
I am confused as to what approach to use, because I did not want to repeat the customComponent and call it 5-6 times ( as many items on the list and data), 
but how do I pass and iterate the right ones ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use boolean in this case. Simply set expanded to the title you need to expand and update your component to compare if expanded is equals to own title. If so, expand it.